# Google Maps V2 API key & package name - some work, some don't

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

my new app which uses Google Maps worked fine until yesterday, when suddenly it didn't show a map anymore. This worked perfectly fine before, for several days.
I got the usual

```
Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I didn't do a thing, and it stopped working. So having no clue what happened, I created a new project, added the new projects package to the api consoles allowed apps...and it worked again. But what if I want to keep the apps package?

So my projects package is

```
package="de.lochmann.woliegtwas"
```

and to allow it in the API console I added:

```
...EE:2D:A1:83:97:20:15;de.lochmann.woliegtwas
```

As I said, this worked fine several days, now, suddenly, without any action on my side it stopped working.

It works again if I change the package and API Key to e.g.

```
package="de.lochmann.woliegtwas2"
...EE:2D:A1:83:97:20:15;de.lochmann.woliegtwas2
```

So, what's happening here? Will it happen again? 
And what if I don't want to change the package name, what if I want to keep my package?

Comment: you have to click generate new android key and pass your sha1 with new package name and use that generated key

Comment: Nope. As said, I already have a key, I added the sha1 and the package name and IT WORKED FOR SEVERAL DAYS, THEN IT STOPPED WORKING. I want to know why it stopped working, if it will happen again and how to keep my app package. Please, read the question.

Comment: check api console is google map api v2 is enabled or not? Sometimes it disable automatically.

Comment: regenerate the keys again...

Comment: please correct your question title, if you create topic think about people that are looking for the same problem in the future.. "some work some don't" doesn't describe problem..

Comment: @deadfish : If I ever get an answer which explains the reason of the problem and gives me a solution, I will gladly change the title of my question, but alas, as long as I don't even understand the problem and only get answers which don't help, I have no clue what a better title could be. For me right now, the problem looks exactly like I stated in the title, some package names work, some don't.

Comment: there are two types of keys: debug and signed, add to your api console this two sha1 keys in this way: put in first line sha1 debug key semicolon and package name (as you did) and in the next line sha1 signed key semicolon and the same package name